# Google directions placeId and string in request uses placeId only in result

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a bunch of stored addresses for routes in my application, but started using autocomplete place_id's for new requests.  If an address is modified in the autocomplete field ('place_changed'), I have a scenario where I submit a request with a place_id and a string.

I didn't see anything that suggests this is not allowed in the docs, but when the results are returned, it appears to only use the place_id provided for both the the origin and destination.

You can replicate it below.  Something I'm doing wrong?

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var routeRequest = {
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
    destination: "19170 Geyserville Ave, Geyserville, CA 95441, USA",
    optimizeWaypoints: false,
    origin: {placeId: "ChIJs2LmmbgQhIARMlmj6BLNK_I"},
    provideRouteAlternatives: false,
    travelMode: "DRIVING",
    waypoints: []
}


directionsService.route(routeRequest, function( result, status ) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(status);
});
```

The above yields:

```
result.routes[0].legs[0].startAddress = "Best Western Dry Creek Inn, 198 Dry Creek Rd, Healdsburg, CA 95448, USA"

result.routes[0].legs[0].endAddress = "Best Western Dry Creek Inn, 198 Dry Creek Rd, Healdsburg, CA 95448, USA"
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the API.  Using a LatLng or a placeId with as the destination works, but using an address or a "place" query does not.

[Issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8979)

These don't work:

```
var routeRequest = {
    origin: {placeId: "ChIJs2LmmbgQhIARMlmj6BLNK_I"},
    destination: {query: "19170 Geyserville Ave, Geyserville, CA 95441, USA"},
    travelMode: "DRIVING"
}

  var routeRequest1 = {
    origin: {placeId: "ChIJs2LmmbgQhIARMlmj6BLNK_I"},
    destination: "19170 Geyserville Ave, Geyserville, CA 95441, USA",
    travelMode: "DRIVING"
}
```

These do:

```
var routeRequest2 = {
    origin: {placeId: "ChIJs2LmmbgQhIARMlmj6BLNK_I"},
    destination: {location: {lat:38.679366,lng:-122.872864}},
    travelMode: "DRIVING"
}

var routeRequest3 = {
    origin: {placeId: "ChIJs2LmmbgQhIARMlmj6BLNK_I"},
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(38.679366,-122.872864),
    travelMode: "DRIVING"
}
```

[test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mwt3LbLx/5/)

Comment: Luckily, I have a lat/lng pair with most stored addresses, so in the interim I am using those.  It's not Ideal, since it changes a general location to a specific address (ex: SF, CA becomes a street address).  Any future request where the user enters a string that is not from the autocomplete results will likely have this issue.  I would need to geocode the entry prior to sending.  Hope this gets fixed!

Comment: Google allows storing the placeId in your database indefinitely, you should be able to use that.  But they should fix this, it is definitely a regression.

Comment: If I'm getting the placeId from the 'place_changed' event in autocomplete, this is not triggered when an address is pasted into a field.  Should I create a geocode request in this scenario?

Comment: You could try reverting to the ["frozen" version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).  I haven't tried that, but it still uses the "old" interface (`origin Type:  LatLng|string), at least according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.21/reference#DirectionsRequest).

Comment: I ended up submitting the request using the place's formatted_address field for now and saving the place name manually.  If I come across a better solution or google addresses the issue I'll update with an answer.